# Open url from transparent activity

Tags: java, android

How to open an url in specifying browser from transparent activity?
I'm using the code:

```
public void open() {
            Log.d("info","start");
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("http://rambler.ru"));
    i.setAction("com.android.browser");
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
    i.setComponent(comp);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(
            i);
    finish();

}
```

but it doesn't work.
Browser is already opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
String url= "your url"
final Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: But I need to specify a browser, (maybe user want to open it not with default browser,example: opera mini, or opera mobile which is different) This code isn't that what I want

Comment: see if there is more than one browser available, user will be prompted with the choice to choose the browser.

Comment: I don't want that :) I want to open it programmatically in a browser that is choosed in preferences